# Getting SPL file with jobID

Tags: winapi, spooler, print-spooler-api

I am developing a print monitor in c++. But I'm having trouble getting the file SPL.
After much research I discovered that I had to insert the  path of the folder where you store the .spl files in spoolerDirectory key.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers\'printername'\SpoolDirectory
>   = c:\windows\system32\spool\printers

The problem that this change only takes effect after restarting the spool service.

As I am monitoring jobs printing, when I restart the spooler i will lose all my objects.

There is another way to solve my problems?
Tanks!

Comment: What is the actual problem? You install your app, set the folder in the Registry, restart the service and/or Windows, and then you are monitoring from that point on.

Comment: The following page contains info about reading the spool data for a given JobId, the naming conventions for SPL files, etc:  http://www.undocprint.org/winspool/spool_files

Comment: Exactly what I do. For each queue there is a dedicated monitor. So when a new queue is added  the monitor performs all settings for queue. but  there when it restarts the service spooler the information from the previous queues are lost

Comment: Are you talking about a port monitor or just an application you developed that monitors print jobs?  If it's a port monitor, then yes, when the spooler stops your monitor will also be stopped since it runs as a thread under the spooler process.  You will need to save information somewhere such as the registry if you want it to persist between restarts of the spooler.